Continuous, convex function on a compact set is constant
Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous, convex. Let $\Omega = \{a\leq |x| \leq b\}, a, b > 0,$ be a spherical shell. Suppose $f$ attains a maximum at a point $x_0 \in \text{int}(\Omega).$ I wish to prove $f$ is constant.
I am rather stuck with this proof. The response here provides some guidance for a slightly different problem, but fails to work completely here because $\Omega$ is not convex.
Clearly, the problem is that, because $\Omega$ is not convex, $L$ may not lie in the $\Omega$. Thus, I am instead thinking of drawing a line $L$ directed "radially" through $x_0$ that intersects the boundaries of $\Omega$ at two boundary points $y_1, y_2$. I conclude from this that
\begin{align}
f(x_0) \leq sf(y_1) + (1-s)f(y_2) \leq \text{max}(f(y_1), f(y_2)), 
\end{align}
so that either $f(y_1)$ or $f(y_2)$ is also a maximum point, but am not sure where to continue from there.

You can use the argument to show that $f$ is constant on $B(x_0,\varepsilon)$. Let $g$ be the restriction of $f$ to the interior of $\Omega$. Then $M=g^{-1}({f(x_0)})$ is open. However, by continuity $M$ is also closed. However, the interior of $\Omega$ is connected and hence $g$ is constant on the interior of $\Omega$. By continuity $f$ is constant on $\Omega$.

Also, did you happen to mean that $f$ is locally convex on $\Omega$ instead of convex? For a convex function you would need a convex domain of definition (i.e. $\Omega$ convex), which is not the case.
